# VLOOK Excel results does not match Power Query Merge

Tags: excel, vlookup, powerquery

1. I have Created Power query to perform VLOOK on two tables using merge.
2. When I Merge them using Full Outer, the result is not same as VLOOKUP Excel.

It seems that Excel VLOOKUP formula takes first instance of match and does not goes further.

```
Table2 
Apple 2 fruit
Grapes 14 fruit
Grapes 15 fruit
Grapes 16 fruit
Banana 22 fruit
Banana 23 fruit
Banana 24 fruit
Banana 25 fruit

Table1
prod sno (VLOOKUP)
Apple 1
Grapes 14
Grapes 14
Banana 22
Banana 22

=VLOOKUP(A2,Table2[#All],2,FALSE)

let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table4, {"prod"}, Table2, {"prod"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table2", {"snum"}, {"Table2.snum"})
in
#"Expanded Table2"

RESULT FROM PQ FOR VLOOKUP

prod Table2.snum
Apple 1
Apple 2
Grapes 14
Grapes 15
Grapes 16
Grapes 14
Grapes 15
Grapes 16
Banana 22
Banana 22
Banana 23
Banana 23
Banana 24
Banana 24
Banana 25
Banana 25
```

Comment: Please provide more detail to clarify, for example, what is in A2 in your VLOOKUP; what is Table4 (you reference it in PQ but I don't see it in your posted data; and exactly what you expect for output from your merge in PQ.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the expand step you are already using. Assuming XXX is column name from the merge step, add add column... custom column... with formula

```
= Table.FirstN([XXX],1)
```

Then right click column XXX and remove it. Expand the new column instead

That will just pick up a single result from the merge, the top row